# Hierarchical data binding with nested ListViews in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, .net-3.5, listview

I have some data that has a detail table. I want the data to be presented in a ListView. I want the detail data to appear as a nested ListView when you select an item in the original list. I can't seem to figure out how to get the data binding to work.

Here's what I have so far, (the problem is the `{Binding Path=FK_History_HistoryItems}`):

```
<ListView Name="lstHistory" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource History}}" SelectionChanged="lstHistory_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}" Header="Description" Width="150" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Total, Converter={StaticResource moneyConvert}}" Header="Total" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource categoryAggregate}}" Header="Categories" Width="100" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Border>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Border Name="presenter"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                    <GridViewRowPresenter />
                                </Border>
                                <Border Name="details" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="5"
                                        BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                                    <StackPanel Margin="5">
                                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FK_History_HistoryItems}">
                                            <ListView.View>
                                                <GridView>
                                                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Ammount}" Header="Ammount" Width="100" />
                                                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Category}" Header="Category" Width="100" />
                                                </GridView>
                                            </ListView.View>
                                        </ListView>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="details" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                <Setter TargetName="presenter" Property="Background" Value="Navy"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="presenter" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

Comment: What output do you get from the binding not working?

(And just so you know, "Amount" has one "m"...)

Comment: It works for me with the same data setup as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350214/wpf-use-a-listbox-in-a-template-that-will-be-the-template-of-another-listbox.  What data set up and sources are you using?

Comment: It's Compact SQL Server 2008 with a History table and its detail table HistoryItems with a FK relation called FK_History_HistoryItems. It would work with a TreeView and a HierarcicalDataTemplate, but that doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: Just to confirm, you get the History list showing correctly and it's only the detail which doesn't show?  Can you show me how you're declaring your datasource?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you need to bind to the SelectedItem of the original list:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lstHistory, Path=SelectedItem}">
```

And then set the datatemplate/view as needed. If you don't want to use ElementName for the binding you could also use RelativeSource but I find ElementName is easier to read and understand.

Comment: I don't think that's quite what I need. I need to bind to the related table on the selected FK from the first table.

In fact, the second list view IS INSIDE the SelectedItem of lstHistory, so I don't see how this does much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your problem line to the following:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FK_History_HistoryItems}">
```

With that change, the control works beautifully.  I have been working on something similar to no avail.  I really like your work on this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the Trigger to work, You will need to set the ControlTemplate TargetType:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
```

Without the TargetType being specified (as a Selectable type), the XAML rendering will be confused...