# Is there any way to nest grouping in a listview? Or do I have to use a TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, grouping

Basically, I have a collection of `Foo`s.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string SubSection { get; set; }

    public string item { get; set; }
}
```

I want my Foo's to be grouped by Section, then by SubSection.

```
Section A
 Section A1
  - Item A1.0
  - Item A1.1
 Section A2
  - Item A2.0
  - Item A2.1
  - Item A2.2
Section B
... etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treeview could be a solution, or you could use a listview and provide your own style template which supports the display of your nested data through binding. Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353678/hierarchical-data-binding-with-nested-listviews-in-wpf).

Answer (score 1):

There is a great sample of combining the ListView with a [Treeview on Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_treelistview_control.aspx). Either you have to implement your own or use a third party library (like Telerik) to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use grouping in a ListView (which has somehow a slight performance issue with grouping), you can use a TreeView and assign a template for the design of each node.